# Altium Designer: Copy room format does not modify polygon net name

Tags: altium, routing

I have a multichannel PCB with channels named U1, U2 and U3. I'm trying to copy the format of one channel to other two:

- component placement,
- routing,
- polygons.

In the first place I was facing that polygons does not copied on their own. Finally I found out that I should check "Copy all objects touching the room":

[image]

However they still don't have propper net names:

[image]

As you can see the polygon have Lo_U1 net name (the same as the first source room) instead of Lo_U2 (as the current room is U2).

I can do it manually of course. But there should be a better solution.

Comment: My impression is that room handling in Altium is quite buggy in general for anything except the most simple cases. It can help to join vias in polygon by extra trace (making them connected to correct net even without the polygon in place), but it is more my personal experimental observation than any consistent advice.

Comment: @Martin did not help in my case: I tried to put a track between a pad and a via placed on the copper area. But the track become the ssame net as the copper area :(